# Solr AND / Must conflict

Tags: solr, liferay

I've noticed a confict between the default AND operator and requests using the MUST query logic. I think I've read about this previously.

If I run the query:

```
companyId:10155 blue widgets
```

I get 5 results. That is all the documents that match companyId=10155 **AND** have blue **AND** widgets in the document fields.

The following request brings back a huge number of documents.

```
+companyId:10155 blue widgets
```

Basically those that match companyId = 10155 **OR** have blue and widgets in the document fields.

Can anyone shed some more light on why this is?

The +companydId10155is added by the CMS (Liferay) and changing this would affect other requests.

There is an easy solution. Search for

```
+companyId:10155 +blue +widgets
```

with the default OR q.OP but my development team don't believe what I've told them!